# Pycharm Warn on re-assignment of unused variable ('re-declaration')

Tags: python, pycharm, pylint

We recently had an issue where a junior developer re-initialized a class attribute in the init method, thinking that they were creating a new variable.

```
def __init__(self):
    self.foo = "foobar"
    self.bar = "bar"
    self.foo = "barfoo"
```

Rather than saying "don't do that again" I'd like to take advantage of tools that can detect this kind of issue. I understand that pylint and similar tools will catch this but was wondering if pycharm has a feature for this as well, that would give an immediate visual cue when this occurs. I've seen in the settings a check that can be set for warning on redeclaration of methods, but nothing for this particular scenario. Does anyone know if this is possible?